# sram cx1 without the sram cx1 crankset?

Tags: gears

I'm thinking of upgrading to sram cx-1 and discs for next season but would like to keep the current crank set based power meter I have.

Can anyone think of a reason why I could not use the current Shimano crank set I have with an 11 speed compatible single retaining chain ring designed for said purpose (like: http://www.hopetech.com/product/retainer-ring-110-pcd/) and would have to go with the sram cx1 crankset?

Answer (score 5):

Strangely enough, everything seems to say that 11 speed [plays nicely together](http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/09/bikes-and-tech/drivetrain-compatibility-hidden-in-plain-sight_303199) - chain widths, etc.

The crankset area (since you're running a 1x11) is effectively independent of the stuff going on in the rear (where the CX-1 groupset has a rear derailleur, shifter, cassette, etc.). So, you shouldn't have to change to a SRAM CX-1 crankset (unless you wanted to make everything match for some reason).

Comment: But what about the special tooth cross-section of SRAM 1x11 and it's resistance to chain dropping?

Comment: SRAM X-Sync is licensed to other manufacturers , or you can get the ring from SRAM themselves. In regards to the hidden bolt spec'd on the ring if you get it from SRAM, [this link](http://www.cxmagazine.com/sram-force-cx1-1x-single-chainring-cyclocross-drivetrain-weight-price-review) states "The X-SYNC chainrings and Force CX1 rear derailleur will be backwards-compatible with 10-speed shifters and chains, but rings are built for SRAM cranks (Red, Force) featuring the hidden chainring bolt, yet should be compatible with any 110BCD crankset after removing the hidden bolt nut, according to SRAM."

Comment: The claim (by SRAM) is that if you mix a non-specially designed ring with the rest of the cx1 system, you might get chain dropping. How this holds in practice remains to be seen if you use a plain old ring (or a ring which isn't exactly X-SYNC) is a different matter (and the original asker states he's going to use a special ring). In any case, the answer is that if you select the right ring, you should be able to put it on a different crankset and it should perform fine.